# what does this mean: SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller:

```
 public ActionResult Detail(string title, string directory)
{

  ScormModule module = ZincService.ScormService.GetScormModule(title, directory);


  if (module != null)
  {
      ViewBag.TrainingModuleId = module.ScormModuleId;
      ViewBag.ScormModuleUrl = module.RelativeHtmlPath + '/' + module.EntryPointRef;
      ViewBag.WindowWidth = module.LaunchWidth;
      ViewBag.WindowHeight = module.LaunchHeight;
      ViewBag.title = module.Title;
      return View(module);
  }
  else
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Scorm", new { area = "Admin" });
}
```

then Detail.aspx file where i call a javascript function:

```
<div class="col3">
    <a id="training-launch-button" href='javascript:OpenScormModuleWindow("<%: ViewBag.ScormModuleUrl %>", <%:  ViewBag.title %>, <%:  ViewBag.WindowWidth %>, <%:  ViewBag.WindowHeight %>);' class="button">Launch</a>
</div>
```

Then OpenScormModuleWindow:

```
function OpenScormModuleWindow(trainingModuleUrl, title, width, height)
{
   console.log(trainingModuleUrl);
   trainingModuleWindow = window.open(trainingModuleUrl, title, "width=" + width + ", height=" + height);
   trainingModuleWindow.focus();
}
```

`ViewBag.ScormModuleUrl = "/SCORM/SellingWindows/a001index.html"`

I never get the output of `console.log(trainingModuleUrl);`
when i hit the launch button i get the error in question and it point to some weird line that is nowhere in my code?

```
var _waxArr; var o = document.getElementById('cosymantecbfw');
o.addEventListener('waxSetArr', function(evt) { _waxArr = evt.detail; }); 
function waxGetElement(i) { return _waxArr[i]; }
```

i searched for this code but does not find it

can someone help please?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your title have any spaces?

If it does, try this

```
<div class="col3">
    <a id="training-launch-button" href='javascript:OpenScormModuleWindow("<%:ViewBag.ScormModuleUrl %>", "<%:  ViewBag.title %>", <%:  ViewBag.WindowWidth %>, <%:  ViewBag.WindowHeight %>);' class="button">Launch</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yes it does i added the quotes thanks! now i get an error: Unhandled exception at line 4, column 5 in http://localhost:11508/Scripts/new.js

0x80070057 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid argument. 

it is on the line trainingModuleWindow = window.open(trainingModuleUrl, title, "width=" + width + ", height=" + height); thanks

Comment: Try hardcoding your first argument (trainingModuleUrl), probably the problem is in it, as you say "I never get the output of console.log(trainingModuleUrl); when i hit the launch button"

Answer (score 4):

Note the "co[**symantec**]bfw".

I think this can be traced to a Norton plugin in your browser.