# IE-11 gives error while opening node-red UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have node-red application, which is implemented using docker/container. When I start UI In IE-11, it does not show the flow, instead gives blank screen. In F12edge it shows error : Script1006: Expected ')' in vendor.js (82,13).

The flow runs fine in the background just the UI does not open in IE. When I tried opening UI in Chrome, Firefox - it works fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSz48.png)

Comment: It sounds like there's a syntax error in your external script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does this mean: SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457827/what-does-this-mean-script1006-expected)

Comment: Also, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299076/script1006-error-internet-explorer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732066/script1006-expected)

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that IE's js parser is seeing `.eval` as the keyword `eval` and expecting `eval(...)`.

Therefore try :

```
a['eval'].call(a, b);
```

Comment: I am generating docker image/container from my node-red flow. Not sure how would I make change to vendor.js

Comment: I understand in principle what you're saying but don't know that particular architecture. You may need to patch one of the libs or transform its output with an adaptor.

Comment: Testing my theory should be pretty simple. Write some test code comprising an object with an `.eval()` method - see if IE-11 gives the same error when the method is called.

Comment: IE11 has no problem parsing `a.eval.call(a, b)`. Note that though `eval` is a built-in function it isn't a keyword, and the built-in function can be referenced without following it with parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for testing nnnnnn. But surely, if `eval` works without parentheses, then it can't be a function and it's difficult to see that it is anything other than a keyword. Do you have a reference so support what you say?

Comment: I didn't say it "works" without parentheses in the sense of the function being invoked, I said it can be *referenced* without parentheses, as any function can. `var x = eval;` is valid JS, and so is `eval.call(null, "1+1")`. In any case in the OP's code `a.eval` does seem to be a function or the `.call()` part wouldn't make sense, but given it is a property of `a` I wouldn't think it is the built-in eval function. Do you have a reference to support what you say?

Comment: No! From what you say, my suggestion is wrong and I'll most likely delete this answer. If there's something about `eval` that I don't know, then I'm keen to learn about it from an authoritative source.

Comment: And sorry for my misunderstanding of your referenced/parentheses point. I've got it now.